# Ext JS 4.2 - How to create a header like the one at KitchenSink sample?

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I need to create a header like the one at [KitchenSink](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/)(*Classic theme*) sample:

[image: KitchenSink Sample Header]

How can I learn its CSS and usage?

Comment: I don't think it's a real part of ExtJS. It's custom CSS. Find `#app-header-title` and its CSS. The positioning is part of ExtJS though. It looks like a (custom) `KitchenSink.view.Header`: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/all-classes.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a custom element that extends the very generic Ext.Container:

```
Ext.define("KitchenSink.view.Header", {
    extend: Ext.Container,
    xtype: "appHeader",
    id: "app-header",
    height: 52,
    layout: {type: "hbox",align: "middle"},
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [{xtype: "component",id: "app-header-title",html: "Ext JS Kitchen Sink",flex: 1}];
        if (!Ext.getCmp("options-toolbar")) {
            this.items.push({xtype: "themeSwitcher"})
        }
        this.callParent()
    }
});
```

Most of its styling happens in custom CSS though. See CSS for `#app-header-title`.

Comment: everything is OK except it doesn't apply the transient effect despite I included `#app-header` and `#app-header-title` CSS definitions.

Comment: What transient effect? You mean the gradient? That's in `#app-header`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your care and patient. it works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

This is a tricky part of learning ExtJS.  I use 'Inspect Element' with chrome (right click the header in chrome and goto Inspect Element) to figure out what CSS class I need to overwrite and where I need to set the 'cls' property .

Comment: @talha06 Hah, you modded me down?  If you inspect it, you will see the CSS styles and the classes that are being used, which is what you're asking about. Not sure why that deserved a down mod.

Comment: I didn't vote you down. It's not a single css property and when I try to merge properties like this way, I couldn't get the right header. The icon isn't shown properly.

Comment: the downvote is probably because you are submitting an answer that's not an answer, this is what the comments section on the question is for.

Comment: I wasn't able to post comments yet when I originally posted that answer, not enough rep at the time